# Is there a way to write a really long HTML attribute value in more than one line?

Tags: html

Trying to keep my HTML readable. Often my HTML attribute has a really long URL for it's value

Example:

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/25th-anniversary-of-armenias-independence-6257593681969152.2-hp2x.jpg"
     data-alt-src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/us-voter-registration-day-reminder-5701453076234240-hp2x.gif" />
```

While these aren't too long, sometimes the URL can be much more extensive. These long lines look terrible in my editor (using WebStorm). It doesn't work if I cut the long URL into multiple lines. I use "+" to concatinate strings in Java or other programming languages, but I have no idea what to do in HTML.

I feel like this is a stupid question, but I had no luck searching for a simple answer. Could you guys help me out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the code should still work even if you cut the line in half. HTML will view the entire bit of code as one line until it hits the line break, the ">". If your editor is giving you an error on the broken line try running it and if it doesn't work still then there might be another issue. Just make sure that you don't put a space in between it. So for example

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016
/25th-anniversary-of-armenias-independence-6257593681969152.2-hp2x.jpg"

data-alt-src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/us-
voter-registration-day-reminder-5701453076234240-hp2x.gif" />
```

Would work but

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/25th-
   anniversary-of-armenias-independence-6257593681969152.2-hp2x.jpg"

data-alt-src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016
  /us-voter-registration-day-reminder-5701453076234240-hp2x.gif" />
```

Would not.

Comment: Wow. That worked, thank you. I still don't understand what the difference is tough. I'll try to check it out.

Comment: Did you run the code or did your editor give you that error? I'm just curious because I ran the code you gave in jsfiddle just to double check and it loaded the image fine as long as there were no spaces! Maybe check to see if its tabbed which could also be the problem.

Comment: Ah, now I see. So basically you can't indent after the line break, because that would be space characters in middle of the URL. Thank you, that helps.

Comment: I believe that is the problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Create a constant file which contains your long url and import them.
To make string concatenation it can be done something like.

```
    var str = 'https://www.google.com' +
        '/logos/doodles/2016/' +
        '25th-anniversary-of-armenias-' +
        'independence-6257593681969152.2-hp2x.jpg';
    <img src=str data-alt-src=str />
```

**Note** `' '` and `" "` should be used differently 
`<img src="http://'+variable+'.jpg" data-alt-src="" />`
There are also html beautifier available use them [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/10.0/reformatting-source-code.html)

Comment: This seems hopeful, but I don't understand how you use variables in HTML. I can declare the variable in <script></script>, but the HTML won't recognize it, will it?

Comment: Thanks for the link to formatting features! Handy tool.

Comment: It was a suggestion. Kind of creating dynamic div or script which will populate those long urls. You need to implement based on your needs. But I tend to answer how to split long urls.

Comment: Well I will look into those. Thank you!

Comment: mostly you need to have proper code linter and code formatter. It will do trick for you. Honestly there should not be any hard coded urls, not best of coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can break the line after you finish "" of your image source, if you break your line in between your image src then it wouldn't work because it'll consider the space as your image url

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/25th-anniversary-of-armenias-independence-6257593681969152.2-hp2x.jpg"

 data-alt-src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2016/us-voter-registration-day-reminder-5701453076234240-hp2x.gif" />
```

Comment: I understand that. I was wondering what people do for long URLs within the " ". Do you just have to leave it however long it is?